# Core Data lightweight migration renamed property keep renaming id all the time?

Tags: ios, core-data, xcode5

I'm using xcode 5 to develop an app for iPhone, I use lightweight migration to update the Core Data schema.

I create a User entity in model version 1, `User` has a property called `nameA`.

In model version 2, I rename `User`'s `nameA` to `nameB`, I set `nameB`'s renaming id to `nameA`. This step is successful, previous value of `nameA` can be found in `nameB`.

Then I create model version 3 to add another entity called `House`, and I found in version 3, `User`'s `nameB` still has its renaming id set to `nameA`

I think in model version 3, `User`'s `nameB` should not has a renaming id, because model version 3 is based on version 2, and in version 3 I did not change anything of `User` entity

So should I delete the renaming id of `User`'s `nameB`? or just leave it there?

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1):

You should leave it there. Your users may not have upgraded to version 2 of your core data schema. When those users upgrade from v1 to v3 they will need to know how to migrate from nameA to nameB

Answer (score -2):

If you use lightweight migration you should not be editing the migration scheme at all. The whole point of lightweight migration is that you do not have to care about renaming ids and other such things - it's automatic!

Here is your workflow:

- create a new version
- activate it
- make your model changes
- for subsequent versions, repeat the above

That's all. The changes you describe (they are all lightweight compatible) should just work.

Comment: I think you are wrong.
According to Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide, Chapter Lightweight Migration, we should set renaming id when rename property.
And my question is one step further. Any one can help???

Comment: Maybe you should consolidate your questions (including [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19592423/427083)) into one and make clear what you actually want to achieve and what is not working.

Comment: Hello, Mundi! I just want to know what value the renaming id should be set in the 3rd data model version. The apple's document doesn't talk about this kind of situation, I'm afraid things may go wrong in the future.
Furthermore I notice this sentence in apple's document:"The renaming identifier creates a “canonical name,” so you should set the renaming identifier to the name of the property in the source model (unless that property already has a renaming identifier)." This makes me more confused, it means if I change nameB to nameC in data model version 3, I should not set nameC's renaming id?

Comment: I ask this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19592423/how-many-migration-steps-does-core-data-lightweight-migration-have) to affirm my conjecture about the process of lightweight migraion. If my conjecture is right I think renaming
id of nameB in 3rd data model should be cleared. Then the default value filled be xcode is wrong.